# How to scale the entire contents of a subplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subplot

I can't find a way to scale an entire subplot (text, lines, etc). Everything I've tried (annotation_custom with coord_cartesian, ggdraw and draw_plot) scales the bounding box but not the contents.

I would like to avoid rendering the plot and then using the image. Any help appreciated.

Sample code:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(1 ,2, 3), y= c('a', 'b', 'c'))
g <- ggplot(data = mydata) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) 
ggdraw(g + draw_plot(g, x=1, y= 1,width=1,height=1,scale=0.2))
```

Result:

[A plot embedded in itself as subplot, with only the bounding box scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbd1A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you're asking. If this is about how to include and scale a (gg)plot *within* a (gg)plot, here's a minimal reproducible example

```
gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
gg2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_point()

gg1 + annotation_custom(
    ggplotGrob(gg2),
    xmin = 25, xmax = 34, ymin = 3.5, ymax = 5.5)
```

[image]

The dimensions of the subplot are determined by the coordinates `(xmin, ymin)` and `(xmax, ymax)`.

---

### Update

In response to your comment, perhaps this is what you're after?

```
library(grid)
library(png)
fn <- tempfile("plot", fileext = "png")
ggsave(filename = fn, plot = gg2, device = "png")
img <- readPNG(fn)
gg1 + annotation_custom(
    rasterGrob(img, interpolate = T),
    xmin = 25, xmax = 28, ymin = 3.5, ymax = 5)
```

The idea is to save the subplot in a temporary PNG file; we can then use png::readPNG`with`grid::rasterGrob` to display the PNG as a custom annotation within the main plot.

[image]

Comment: That will work. Up to a point. Changing my example code to use annotation_custom (replacing the ggdraw line with g + annotation_custom( ggplotGrob(g), xmin = 1, xmax = 1.25, ymin = 1, ymax = 1.25) ) shows that at smaller sizes it collapses just like in my sample image that used ggdraw.

Comment: @jawondo I'm confused about what you expected. The subplot is not a (raster) image; it's a plot grob. I guess it comes down to me not understanding what you mean by *"scales the bounding box but not the contents."*

Comment: It seems that when you change the size of the grob, its contents are not simply scaled to fit. You'll notice that the points in the inset are the same size as the ones in the enclosing plot (or very close). As is the text. What I am looking for is a way to scale a subplot like you would scale an image. I thought because plots can be saved in EPS format, that this might be possible within ggplot2.

Comment: @jawondo *"scale a subplot like you would scale an image"* Well then why not do that? I give a minimal example in my update. What does the fact that a (gg)plot can be saved as an EPS have to do with how the *ggplot object* is treated within `ggplotGrob`? As I said, when you use `ggplotGrob` you are plotting a (gg)plot grob; when using `rasterGrob` you're plotting a raster image.

Comment: The quality of the scaled PNG is what I was trying to avoid by keeping it within ggplot (my subplot is very simple). But it may be the nature of the internals of ggplot. I will try your suggestion, but with a vector format. I have just found some info here: https://davetang.org/muse/2019/02/22/importing-vector-images-into-r/. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @jawondo Ok I see your point. However, I would argue that if you try to scale the plot to such dimensions where `ggplotGrob` does not scale the plot properly anymore the loss of quality due to rasterisation should be negligible. Either way, perhaps leave the question open and see if somebody else comes up with a better/different idea.